# Summation involving unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind: $\sum_{n=0}^{l}{{n+v \brack n+2}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations, stirling-numbers

$$\sum_{n=0}^{l}{{n+v \brack n+2}}$$

I know that at $v=2$, the summation above is equal to $l+1$, and at $v=3$, the summation is equal to $$\binom{l+4}{3}-1.$$ What does the summation generally evaluate to? Thanks a lot, family! The notation $\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{x}{y}$ denotes the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: Please take out the image and type the formula as you did with the binomial.

Comment: I have a hard time getting the code for the Stirling number used above here on math.stackexchange. If you know the code I can use to type that [] notation for the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind, I will appreciate it so much.

Comment: Use `$\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{x}{y}$` to get $\genfrac[]{0pt}{}{x}{y}$.

Comment: Thank you @Misha Lavrov!

Comment: alternatively there is {x \brack y}. ${x\brack y}.$

Comment: Thank you @Phicar.